# Trigonometric Identities Question

Tags: trigonometry

If $A$ is obtuse and $\sin A=\sqrt{3}/2$, find, without a calculator, $\cos2A$,$ \cos4A$, $\sin4A$, and $\cos(\frac{1}{2}A)$.

My working:

$$O=3^{1/2}, H=2; A=1$$

$$\cos2A=1-2(\sin A)^2$$
$$\cos2A=1-2\left(\frac34\right)$$
$$\cos2A=1-\frac32$$
$$\cos2A=-\frac12$$

$$\cos(4A)=[\cos(2A)]^2-[\sin(2A)]^2$$
$$\cos(4A)=\frac14-[2\sin A\cos A]^2$$
$$\cos(4A)=\frac14-\left[\frac{3^{1/2}}{2}\right]^2$$
$$\cos(4A)=\frac14-\frac34$$
$$\cos(4A)=-\frac12$$

$$\sin(4A)=2\sin(2A)\cos(2A)$$
$$\sin(4A)=2\left(\frac{3^{1/2}}{2}\right)\left(-\frac12\right)$$
$$\sin(4A)=-\frac{3^{1/2}}{2} $$
(the answer given is positive, though when I worked it out on the calculator it was negative)

$$(\cos A)^2=\frac12\left[1-\cos\left(\frac12 A\right)\right]$$
$$1/4=\frac12\left[1-\cos\left(\frac12 A\right)\right]$$
$$\cos\left(\frac12 A\right)=\frac12$$

What I wanted to ask was, will the answer always come out right if I plug in the the correct values of $\sin A$, $\cos A$, etc with the right sign, and is there any way of checking if the sign of my answer is right? Also, is my answer for $\sin(4A)$ right or wrong?

(ps is there any website I could go to if I wanted to find out more about this level (A level) of trig?)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your formatting is a nightmare, and so bad I quit editing it for there is too much to do. In any case I think in some cases you could have done it more easily (for instance $\cos 2x=2\cos^2 x-1$ is very useful, more than $\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x$). In any case, you should know from memory that $A=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ or $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$, but you know $A$ is obtuse, so...

Comment: You can use unit circle for signs, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle)

Comment: Bad title. :(  .